# Tensorflow: creating a diagonal matrix with input on the sub/superdiagonals

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 10
X = tf.ones([N,], dtype=tf.float64)
D = tf.linalg.diag(X, k=1, num_rows=N+1, num_cols=N+1)

print(D)
```

which, based on the [TF2 documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/diag), I expect to return an 11x11 tensor with X inserted on the first superdiagonal (even without the optional `num_rows` and `num_cols` arguments). However, the result is

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]], shape=(10, 10), dtype=float64)
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you why this doesn't work, but I don't know what the fix is. Probably raise a github issue.

If you look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L2073) line in the `array_ops.py`. It does a compatibility check `tf.compat.forward_compatible` to see if the compatibility window has expired. Which returns `False` (For both TF 2.0.0 and 2.1.0rc0) . Due to this reason it executes

`return gen_array_ops.matrix_diag(diagonal=diagonal, name=name)`

which you can see that none of `k`, `num_rows`, `num_cols` are used while calling. So the method is currently completely oblivious to these parameters if that `tf.compat.forward_compatible` check fails.

Comment: Thanks! For now, I just went to the source file and edited it accordingly. I'll submit an issue on GitHub eventually